# Nested Linq Queries doesn't behave as expected

Tags: linq

My question is very simple, given following piece of code at the beginning

```
var list = new[] {
    new { name = "lixiang", age = 14 },
    new { name = "lixiang", age = 16 },
    new { name = "lidian", age = 14 }
};
var people = list.GroupBy(x => x.name);
```

This would give me a compiler error as expected since people is a Group of records:

```
var x1 = people.Select(x => x.name);
```

But what I don't understand is, why this one successfully compile?

```
var x2 = people.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.name));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`people` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, A'>>`, where `A'` is your anonymous type.  `IGrouping<string, A'>` has no `name` property, which is why the first select fails.

However, `x` in the second example is `IGrouping<string, A'>`, which inherits `IEnumerable<A'>`.  This makes `y` typed as `A'`, which does have a `name` property.  This is why the second example compiles fine.

Note that `x2` will have the type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.  To flatten this, change the outer `Select` to `SelectMany`:

```
var x3 = people.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.name));
```

In this example, `x3` will have the type `IEnumerable<string>`.

This is all academic, of course, since `people.Select(x => x.name)` would be a much faster way to get the same result (assuming that ordering is not significant).